# Can an Indian citizen visit Dubai on a layover?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, dubai, transit-visas

I am an Indian citizen and am travelling from New York to India via Emirates Airlines. There is a 7-hour layover at Dubai international Airport (DXB). I want to visit Dubai for a couple of hours. Do I need a transit visa? If so, how do I obtain one?

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other question is about transiting airside. This question is about leaving the airport during transit.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to obtain a visa in advance. Nationals of India are not eligible for a [UAE visa on arrival](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx).

You [can](https://www.dubaivisa.net/EK-OnlineVisa/Countries.aspx) apply for your visa online. After you have booked your flight with Emirates, go to [Manage your booking](http://www.emirates.com/SessionHandler.aspx?pub=/english&pageurl=/MYB.aspx&section=MYB) to apply for the visa. When you apply this way, you [do not need a visa stamp](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx) on your passport.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a transit visa to visit Dubai. Contact with Emirates airline to apply for the 96-hour transit visa on your behalf.

Comment: Answers based on personal knowledge and experience are great. Answers that are also based on authoritative references are even better. Do you have any such references?

Comment: Please visit http://www.uae.org.br/Ingles/Consular/transvisa.htm for reference.

Comment: Add this to your answer, quoting the relevant parts of the link. :)